# Packard Bell TS11HR-068GE brightness control doesn't work

Tags: brightness

i did search in google but haven't find anything about this problem for **my**  model laptop: Packard Bell TS11HR-068GE
the graphic card is: NVIDIA GeForce 610M

i am newbie on linux & ubuntu, so pls tell me as simply as possible how can i fix this problem

10x

Answer (score 1):

You can add to grub config an acpi command.

Issue following command to edit `/etc/default/grub`,

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

modify the following lines adding "acpi_backlight=vendor"  like below

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

then  run

```
 sudo update-grub
```

After that restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

### Same solution as one-liner

For this solution no `nano` knowledge is required. It is also handy for multi-machine installation scripts.

```
sudo sed -i 's|^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"|GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"|' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```